# Difference between app.all('*') and app.use('/')

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a useful difference between `app.all("*", … )` and `app.use("/", … )` in Express.js running on Node.js?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In most cases they would work equivalently. The biggest difference is the order in which middleware would be applied:

- `app.all()` attaches to the application's router, so it's used whenever the `app.router` middleware is reached (which handles all the method routes... `GET`, `POST`, etc).

> NOTICE: `app.router` has been deprecated in express 4.x

- `app.use()` attaches to the application's main middleware stack, so it's used in the order specified by middleware, e.g., if you put it first, it will be the first thing to run. If you put it last, (after the router), it usually won't be run at all.

Usually, if you want to do something globally to all routes, `app.use()` is the better option. Also, it has less chance of future bugs, since express 0.4 will probably drop the implicit router (meaning, the position of the router in middleware will be more important than it is right now, since you technically don't even have to use it right now).

Comment: Does this still apply after Express 4.x? app.router was removed.

Comment: You can use `next("route")` with `app.all`, but not with `app.use`.

Comment: @JozefMikusinec Documentation seems to suggest otherwise... https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: Your link doesn't mention next('route'), but I looked at the API, you are right.

Comment: @musicin3d I researched further and found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3133), that confirms that "next() and next('route') have no difference to app.use" (quote). They should change the docs.

Comment: @JozefMikusinec My apologies. I was in a rush and didn't notice you had specified a route in your first comment. TIL! Thanks looking into this. :)

Comment: Would be awesome to update this answer, since it initially warned against future updates

Answer (score 108):

**app.use** takes only one callback function and it's meant for Middleware. Middleware usually doesn't handle request and response, (technically they can) they just process input data, and hand over it to next handler in queue.

```
app.use([path], function)
```

**app.all** takes multiple callbacks, and meant for routing. with multiple callbacks you can filter requests and send responses. Its explained in [Filters on express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763504/filters-on-express-js)

```
app.all(path, [callback...], callback)
```

**app.use** only sees whether url starts with the specified path

```
app.use( "/product" , mymiddleware);
// will match /product
// will match /product/cool
// will match /product/foo
```

**app.all** will match complete path

```
app.all( "/product" , handler);
// will match /product
// won't match /product/cool   <-- important
// won't match /product/foo    <-- important

app.all( "/product/*" , handler);
// won't match /product        <-- Important
// will match /product/
// will match /product/cool
// will match /product/foo
```

Comment: At least in [v4, app.use](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) takes one *or more* middleware functions, not "only one".

Comment: app.use only see whether url starts with specified path;app.all will match complete path. this is main difference.

Comment: @frogcjn no it should not as it ignores the * and / in my question.

Answer (score 21):

- app.use:

  1. inject middlware to your front controller configuring for instance: header, cookies, sessions, etc.
  2. must be written before app[http_method] otherwise there will be not executed.
  3. several calls are processed in the order of writing
- app.all:

  1. (like app[http_method]) is used for configuring routes' controllers
  2. "all" means it applies on all http methods.
  3. several calls are processed in the order of writing

Look at this expressJs code sample:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function frontControllerMiddlewareExecuted(req, res, next){
  console.log('(1) this frontControllerMiddlewareExecuted is executed');
  next();
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('(2) route middleware for all method and path pattern "*", executed first and can do stuff before going next');
  next();
});

app.all('/hello', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('(3) route middleware for all method and path pattern "/hello", executed second and can do stuff before going next');
  next();
});

app.use(function frontControllerMiddlewareNotExecuted(req, res, next){
  console.log('(4) this frontControllerMiddlewareNotExecuted is not executed');
  next();
});

app.get('/hello', function(req, res){
  console.log('(5) route middleware for method GET and path patter "/hello", executed last and I do my stuff sending response');
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(80);
```

Here is the log when accessing route '/hello':

```
(1) this frontControllerMiddlewareExecuted is executed
(2) route middleware for all method and path pattern "*", executed first and can do stuff before going next
(3) route middleware for all method and path pattern "/hello", executed second and can do stuff before going next
(5) route middleware for method GET and path patter "/hello", executed last and I do my stuff sending response
```

Comment: After running this example verbatim on express 4.x, it actually runs all 5 in order.  This is likely due to changes in express in the almost 3 years since this was written, but I just thought I would add this for clarity.

Answer (score 13):

With `app.use()`, the "mount" path is stripped and is not visible to the middleware function:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Mounted middleware functions(`express.static`) are not invoked unless the `req.url` contains this prefix (`/static`), **at which point it is stripped** when the function is invoked.

With `app.all()`, there is no that behavior.

Comment: The question explicitly ask about app.use('/', ...) only.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question which still is true in 2018! A middleware can be mounted with all() too ... the only difference is that the mount path is stripped when executing the middleware.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `app.all()` gets called when a particular URI is requested with any type of request method (POST, GET, PUT, or DELETE)

On other hand `app.use()` is used for any middleware you might have and it mounts onto a path prefix, and will be called anytime a URI under that route is requested.

Here is the documentation for [app.all](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all) & [app.use](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

Comment: thanks but I think you missed the app.all wildcard and app.use root path which make them pretty much exactly the same thing don't they? Except that app.all can take an array of callbacks and app.use can only take one - right?

Answer (score 2):

Two differences all above answers don't mention.

The first one:
`app.all` accepts a regex as its path parameter. `app.use` does NOT accept a regex.

The second one:
`app.all(path, handler)` or `app[method](path, handler)` handlers' `path` must be same to **all** `path`. This is, `app[method]` path is complete.

`app.use(path, handler)`, if `use`'s path is complete, the handler's path must be `/`. If the `use`'s path is the start of the complete path, the handler path must be the rest of the complete path.

```js
app.use("/users", users);

//users.js: the handler will be called when matchs `/user/` path
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("respond with a resource");
});

// others.js: the handler will be called when matches `/users/users` path
router.get("/users", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("respond with a resource");
});
```

```js
app.all("/users", users);

//others.js: the handler will be called when matches `/`path
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("respond with a resource");
});
//users.js: the handler will be called when matches `/users` path
router.get("/users", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("respond with a resource");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main differences:
1. pattern matching (answer given by Palani)
2. `next(route)` won't work inside the function body of middleware loaded using `app.use` . This is stated in the link from the docs:

```
NOTE: next('route') will work only in middleware functions that were loaded by using the app.METHOD() or router.METHOD() functions.
```

Link: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

The working effect of `next('route')` can be seen from the following example:

```
app.get('/',
(req,res,next)=>{console.log("1");
next(route); //The code here skips ALL the following middlewares
}
(req,res,next)=>{next();}, //skipped
(req,res,next)=>{next();}  //skipped
);

//Not skipped
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){console.log("2");next();});
```