# Express middleware: app.use and app.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a difference between

`app.use('/some/path', function(req, res, next() {})`

and

`app.all('/some/path', function(req, res, next() {})`

They are both middleware functions that get called for /some/path requests only, right?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125997/difference-between-app-all-and-app-use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between app.all('\*') and app.use('/')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125997/difference-between-app-all-and-app-use)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is big difference between the use of these two examples. Functions registered with `app.use` are general middleware functions and is called appropriate to their position on the middleware stack, typically inside an `app.configure` function. This type of middleware is usually placed **before** `app.route`, with the exception of error handling functions.

On the other hand `app.all` is a routing function (not usually called middleware) which covers all HTTP methods and is called only **inside** `app.route`. If any of your previous router function matches the  `/some/path` and did not call the `next` callback, `app.all` will not be executed, so `app.all` functions are usually on the beginning of your routing block.

There is also third type of middleware, used in your routing functions, eg.

```
app.get('/some/path', middleware1, middleware2, function(req, res, next) {});
```

which is typicaly used for limiting access or perform general tasks related to `/some/path` route.

For practical application you can use both functions, but be careful of the difference in behaviour when using `app.use` with `/some/path`. Unlike `app.get`, `app.use` strips `/some/path` from the route before invoking the anonymous function.

You can find more in the documentation of [express](http://expressjs.com/api.html).

Comment: This is true for Express 3, but Express 4 handles this a bit differently, and they're closer now.