# Multiple methods on the same route in Express

Tags: express

I have 3 different method responses in the API I'm working on currently set up like this:

```
app.use('/image', require('./routes/image/get'));
app.post('/image', require('./routes/image/post'));
app.put('/image', require('./routes/image/put'));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use `.route()` on your `app`'s `Express` object to reduce some of the redundancy in your route definitions.

```js
app.route('/image')
     .post(require('./routes/image/post'))
     .put(require('./routes/image/put'));
```

There is also `.all()`, which will invoke your handler regardless of the request http method.

#### No `use()`

I've omitted `.use()`, mentioned above, because it is not available on Route objects -- it sets up application middleware. Routers are another layer of middleware (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125997/difference-between-app-all-and-app-use) for an explanation of the difference). If the intent is really to call `.use()`, and not `.get()`, then that line would have to stay, *before* the call to `.route()` (middleware registration order matters).

#### Reusing the same handler for different http methods

If one would prefer to reuse the same handler for a set of methods, in the following style:

```js
app.route("/image").allOf(["post", "put"], function (req, res) {
    //req.method can be used to alter handler behavior.
    res.send("/image called with http method: " + req.method);
});
```

then, the desired functionality can be obtained by adding a new property to `express.Route`'s prototype:

```js
var express = require('express');

express.Route.prototype.allOf = function (methods /*, ... */) {
    "use strict";

    var i, varargs, methodFunc, route = this;

    methods = (typeof methods === "string") ? [methods] : methods;
    if (methods.length < 1) {
        throw new Error("You must specify at least one method name.");
    }

    varargs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        methodFunc = route[methods[i]];
        if (! (methodFunc instanceof Function)) {
            throw new Error("Unrecognized method name: " +
                            methods[i]);
        }
        route = methodFunc.apply(route, varargs);
    }

    return route;
};
```