# How to combine app.post and app.get to one in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make one router for login page post and get request.

below is my code :

```js
  app.get('/login', getLoginPage);
  app.post('/login', doLogin);
```

Here I am using app.all to combine both , but I am not getting any idea how to handle it in all.

What I have tried so far .

```js
app.all('/login', handler); 
var handler = function(req, res){
   console.log(req);
   if(req.method=="POST")
   {
   getLoginPage;
   }
   if(req.method=="GET")
   {
   doLogin
   }
}
```

```js
const {getLoginPage,doLogin} = require('./controller/login');
```

Here app.get and app.post working fine for me except app.all.
Here I am using express js.
Please suggest .

Comment: is this expressJS or something others.?

Comment: yes express js.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24192057/3654837) does that explains why app.all not working for you?

Comment: This concept is called 'routing'. Search on youtube like 'ExpressJS Routes Tutorial' clip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like so (full working example):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.route('/test')
  .get((req, res) => getLoginPage(req, res))
  .post((req, res) => doLogin(req, res))

doLogin = (req, res) => {
  res.send('doLogin');
}

getLoginPage = (req, res) => {
  res.send('getLoginPage');
}

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: i've added a full working example. If you can't make it run please check your node/express version.

Comment: i have installed: node 10.14.1 and use express 4.16.3 - not sure but i would guess it should work with your versions. Isn't that example working for you? How do you test it and what do you expect? When this example is running, a simple get and post request to the route `localhost:3000/test` should reply with either 'doLogin' or 'getLoginPage'

Comment: by mistake, I wrote localhost:4000/test  instead of localhost:4000/login,
Here my aim is to write in one code , not in get() and post() both its increasing number of lines .
Its for learning purpose , I am a newbie to node js and learning it.
Thank you foe the suggestion .

Comment: Always a good approach to decrease lines of code - but in this case you have to distinguish between get and post - either you do it with an `if else` statement on the `req.method` (see @ROAL answer) or you use the callbacks for this. I would recommend the callbacks as it is suggested by the express documentation.

Answer (score 1):

HOISTING!!!

It's really just scope. You have a function expression, not a declaration. Declarations get hoisted but definitions do NOT. So when you call handler, handler is not defined yet since it's function expression comes bellow it.

So no need to change your code, except the order of things. Do this and it will work

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
  if (req.method == "POST") {
    console.log("POST");
  }
  if (req.method == "GET") {
    console.log("GET");
  }
};

app.all("/login", handler);
```

Read about scopes in function declaration vs expression

Answer (score 0):

Try following use method. It will accept all types of methods and you can apply conditions there:

```js
app.use('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
  if(req.method=="POST")
  {
    getLoginPage;
  }
  else if(req.method=="GET")
  {
    doLogin;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the functions in your `app.all` handler.

```js
app.all('/login', handler);
var handler = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        getLoginPage(req, res);
    }
    if (req.method == "GET") {
        doLogin(req, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: after doing this I am getting this error ;
Route.acl() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Comment: @sradha sorry, you're not using `next` in your handlers. I've edited the answer. @DavidJoos has a better suggestion anyways. See his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tried invoking the functions and pass the req and res parameters to those functions

```
app.all('/login', handler); 
function handler(req, res){
  if(req.method=="POST"){
    getLoginPage(req, res);
  } else if(req.method=="GET"){
    doLogin(req, res);
  }
}
```

edit: change to function declaration instead of function expression to avoid hoisting issues