# ExpressJS serve static files on post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, post

I need Express server to serve static files (website). It works in my code well:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var p = path.join(__dirname, '../web/public');
app.use("/files", function (req, res) {
    return res.send("I will do something on server");
});
app.use(express.static(p));
app.use('/*',express.static(p));
let port = 80;
var server = app.listen(port);
```

But when I have a form served by this server, it redirects after submit, and the page displays only something like

> Cannot POST /dashboard/

How can I correctly handle post requests within the meaning of serving static files? I tried to add this right before declaring the port:

```js
app.post(express.static(p));
app.post('/*', express.static(p));
```

But it doesn't work.

PS: my entire page is served (I want that) from index.html. In order to do that, I have in my code that:

```js
app.use(express.static(p));
app.use('/*',express.static(p));
```

How do I "redirect" post requests to index.html?  In this file I have the entire app logic (it is a single page app).

PS2: I really need default submit.  Going around that is not a solution for me (I want to offer the user to save their login and password, and without submitting the form, Google chrome will not offer that to users). And on the other side I really need use POST, as the login form is transferring sensitive data...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file called *dashboard* so there is nothing for `express.static` to serve.

To handle that dashboard route, you can do this:

```js
app.post("/dashboard", function (req, res) {
  return res.send("I will do something with this post");
});
```

If you want to redirect 404 traffic to *index.html*, you can do this **after** all your route definitions:

```js
app.use("/", function (req, res) {
  return res.redirect("/index.html");
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Just one last question before accept. When I call app.use with "/", does it means it catch everything what starts with / ? My understanding of express path was, that it only do that redirection on exact url match (so only on 127.0.0.1/ ).

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped. `app.use` affects everything, but `app.all` works more like you described. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24192057/2185093) answer